# How to troubleshoot telemetry delivery to an Application Insights bucket?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have some powershell code that sends telemetry to Application Insights. We have discovered that telemetry stopped arriving to AI, despite the code being unchanged. There are no errors.

The code uses the following Powershell function to create a telemetry client:

```
function New-TelemetryClient([Parameter(Mandatory)]$InstrumentationKey, $SessionKey)
{
    $MicrosoftApplicationInsightsDll = Get-LibraryFromNuGet Microsoft.ApplicationInsights net46 2.11.0
    Add-Type -Path $MicrosoftApplicationInsightsDll.FullName
    $tc = New-Object Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient
    $tc.Context.InstrumentationKey = $InstrumentationKey
    if (!$SessionKey)
    {
        $SessionKey = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    }
    $tc.Context.Session.Id = $SessionKey
    $tc
}
```

We create a telemetry client object, invoke a bunch of `TrackEvent` methods to send custom events and then call `Flush`. This code works fine from a local machine, but sends no telemetry from a build machine.

Strange is that when we change the Instrumentation Key it does seem to work on the same build machine. So a lot of weird things.

I would like to get diagnostics output for Application Insights, but I cannot find any information on how to turn it on.

So my question is - how can I collect diagnostic messages when sending to Application Insights from Powershell?

Comment: Is there a way to install Fiddler on build machine and see whether it sends and gets rejected or doesn't send at all?

Comment: Here is another option (assuming there is a problem with this ikey and not some connectivity issues): http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/11/07/application-insights-self-diagnostic/

Comment: This is a bit old - not sure whether it still works or not. Application Insigths SDK emits ETW traces which can be viewed with a tool such as PerfView. http://sergeysharp.com/blog/2015/04/16/diagnostic-of-applicationinsights-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options available to troubleshoot Application Insights .NET SDK:

1. Use Fiddler to inspect HTTP requests. This will help to detect issues such as invalid instrumentation key.
2. If AI SDK doesn't make HTTP requests then please follow the following guidance to collect ETW events from AI SDK: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/master/Samples/ETW#tools-to-collect-etw